# Sanity check ext partition size?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ext4, fdisk

I ran resize2fs on a ext4 linux partition and I want to create a partition after it.  However I want to sanity check that the size I put into fdisk afterwards was correct.  What's the best way to sanity check that the size of the partition + the filesystem match up.

NOTE: I used sectors in resize2fs and +sectors in fdisk to do the sizes.  I think this was correct.

Comment: Why not simply use resize2fs / resize4fs to resize the filesystem to the full size of the partition (I think you just run it as resize2fs /dev/XXX and it figures it out for itself)

Comment: Yeah, most docs don't say to do that, but I guess it makes sense to just do all the resizing in fdisk then let resize2fs do the moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it is to resize the filesystem to something smaller than the new size of the partition it is on so that when you create the new partition you can just do `resize2fs /dev/sdX` and it will use the "unallocated" space.

Let me give you an example:

*/dev/sda* is a 20G harddrive and there is one partition, */dev/sda1* which uses all 20G.
Now you want */dev/sda1* and */dev/sda2* of 10G each.
First you resize your filesystem to something smaller than 10G. I'd use 8 or 9G.
Then resize the partion, create the new partition *sda2* and then finally run `resize2fs /dev/sda1` to use  the leftover 1 or 2G.

Let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: I did this on accident last night.  Good to know that actually should work good.

Just get nervous the ext one will end up sized too large and overwrite the EFI partition.  But at least it's for Linux so it shouldn't be that hard to recreate.